# Why does the admin site not care about my custom user's permissions?

Tags: python, django

I started a Django (1.10.3) project with a custom user model, inherited from `AbstractBaseUser`. A couple of weeks into developing the thing, I saw that I needed more granular permissions for admin users, so I extended my user model with `PermissionsMixin`, generated and applied migrations, and updated my `ModelAdmin`.

To try it out I logged in to the admin with my superuser and created a new user with all permissions added manually. When I logged in with that new user, I was greeted by a nice **"You don't have permission to edit anything"**.

So I went to the shell, checked my user's permissions and they were there.

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='new_user')
>>> u.get_all_permissions()
{'admin.add_logentry', ...}
```

However,

```
>>> u.has_perm('admin.add_logentry')
False
```

Now, what `has_perm` does, if the user is not an active superuser, is to call this:

```
def _user_has_perm(user, perm, obj):
    for backend in auth.get_backends():
        if not hasattr(backend, 'has_perm'):
            continue
        try:
            if backend.has_perm(user, perm, obj):
                return True
        except PermissionDenied:
            return False
    return False
```

But,

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_backends
>>> backend = get_backends()[0]  # django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend
>>> backend.has_perm(u, 'admin.add_logentry')
True
```

---

So,

Why are `user.has_perm(perm)` and `backend.has_perm(user, perm)` returning different values?
And ultimately, how can I get the permissions system to work correctly in this scenario?

Comment: Try logging except PermissionDenied. It looks lie it may be returning false too soon. you may need to replace it with pass

Answer (score 1):

I should be ashamed of the actual answer to this. At least I hope there's a lesson to be learned from it. Maybe I can add something along the lines of *"always check your own implementations first"* to my bug fixing heuristics.

The apparent impossibility of those two methods returning different things led me to inspect if I was actually calling them. It turns out that I completely forgot my own implementation of `has_perm`, which I absent mindedly created in order for the user model to be compliant with the admin.
This implementation, of course, only checked for superuser status.

I think that Occam fellow was on to something.